# Clean up a comma-separated list by regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to clean up a tag list separated by comma to remove empty tags and extra spaces. I came up with

```
$str='first , second ,, third, ,fourth   suffix';
echo preg_replace('#[,]{2,}#',',',preg_replace('#\s*,+\s*#',',',preg_replace('#\s+#s',' ',$str)));
```

which works well so far, but is it possible to do it in one replacement?

Comment: Why do this with a regexp? It would be easier to use `split()`, `trim()`, and `array_filter()`.

Comment: What is the exact output you want here?

Comment: Why do you want to remove empty elements? Presumably that represents something, and it happens to be blank. You're losing information by removing that.

Comment: @Barmar because the purpose is to clean up the string, not extract the tags. Then, I have to add another step of `implode`. I find the regex replacement faster and easier.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the expected output is exactly the above echo. The system works, I just wanted to minimize the number of processes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```php
preg_replace('~\s*(?:(,)\s*)+|(\s)+~', '$1$2', $str)
```

Merging the two alternatives into one results in

```php
preg_replace('~\s*(?:([,\s])\s*)+~', '$1', $str)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/f5pB52/1) and the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/jPZ8qj). *Details*:

- `\s*(?:(,)\s*)+` - zero or more whitespaces and then one or more occurrences of a comma (captured into Group 1 (`$1`)) and then zero or more whitespaces
- `|` - or
- `(\s)+` - one or more whitespaces while capturing the last one into Group 2 (`$2`).

In the second regex, `([,\s])` captures a single comma or a whitespace character.

The second regex matches:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:([,\s])\s*)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `([,\s])` - Group 1 (`$1`): a comma or a whitespace
  - `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/jPZ8qj):

```php
<?php
 
$str='first , second ,, third, ,fourth   suffix';
echo preg_replace('~\s*(?:(,)\s*)+|(\s)+~', '$1$2', $str) . PHP_EOL;
echo preg_replace('~\s*(?:([,\s])\s*)+~', '$1', $str);
// => first,second,third,fourth suffix
//    first,second,third,fourth suffix
```

**BONUS**

This solution is portable to all NFA regex flavors, here is a JavaScript demo:

```js
const str = 'first , second ,, third, ,fourth   suffix';
console.log(str.replace(/\s*(?:(,)\s*)+|(\s)+/g, '$1$2'));
console.log(str.replace(/\s*(?:([,\s])\s*)+/g, '$1'));
```

It can even be adjusted for use in POSIX tools like `sed`:

```sh
sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*(([,[:space:]])[[:space:]]*)+/\2/g' file > outputfile
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/SHO9Wp).

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
[\h*([,\h])[,\h]*
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HEEZTX/1). Or alternatively:

```
\h*([,\h])(?1)*
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/fzL4g5/1)

---

- `\h*` - 0+ (Greedy) horizontal-whitespace chars;
- `([,\h])` - A 1st capture group to match a comma or horizontal-whitespace;
- `[,\h]*` - **Option 1**: 0+ (Greedy) comma's or horizontal-whitespace chars;
- `(?1)*` - **Option 2**: Recurse the 1st subpattern 0+ (Greedy) times.

---

Replace with the 1st capture group:

```
$str='first , second ,, third, ,fourth   suffix';
echo preg_replace('~\h*([,\h])[,\h]*~', '$1', $str);
echo preg_replace('~\h*([,\h])(?1)*~', '$1', $str);
```

Both print:

```
first,second,third,fourth suffix
```